# Getting different outcome than teacher

Tags: python

I'm taking a course through Stackskills on python and I'm on iterators and loops. The teacher is getting a different outcome than I am and I was wondering why:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmGJe.png]

Comment: Put a [mre], **as text**, in the question.

Comment: One is doing `sum = sum + num` and the other is doing `sum = sum + sum` thus never incrementing the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
sum = sum + sum # you are only adding sum to itself
```

you should change it to:

```
sum = sum + num # here you will be adding the current list item to sum
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Comment: @coffeedrinkerman no problem. I am glad that I could help you. If my answer helped you please mark it as the answer to your question. Also please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Absolutely, so insanely fast responses.

Comment: @coffeedrinkerman thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the loop your teacher is adding

```py
sum = sum + num # Attention its an n
```

But you are adding:

```py
sum = sum + sum # which is sum = 0 + 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Should have seen that, glad i posted my question here